# What is this Encoding Type Ending With ==?

Tags: decode, encode

Hello I am working in a software company as a junior and old developers have encoded the database with a unknown encoding.

Here is a example :

IOSk3G7SbrKdXDXZtt9UfLI8phfEkowBFTuC5P1/ICLFqawgEFNq1ENWTg0nL1RpCbQEHPMkOOKSCr2MxHW5XIqWoiQUX59E2rbSMH4dxLDCqkx8a/jItk/O316ZdxYIXYxRfiefJ4oMD8fq4thBQ2pPdKT/+6xYwyC2oGpX9NcDnowYFc60ExV6WaoudJ9XDWonCeEaFb7A4ekQN4SijMbSVq5LBXAmAUzhe+L2aHVu0YfFbcZ7GM9y1czGiDeq4o1jksnDmxu9AeEmtCeTB6K6vCwSEjxa2x0/c2Yn16ZYyB40HAaVf3C8LepCfS6futLzkUDK7BwJNrVJ4gzgdQ==

what encoding this could be? I should encode next generated accounts with same encoding..

Comment: Hi, you should firstly ask others at your work; then if no one knows find some encoded data where you _know_ the unencoded data and try to replicate the encoding; also try to find a function you've used. This is something you should be trying to find out within your company. I'm a little bit baffled why no one would remember what encoding is used but if it's not documented don't stick more data in the database. Do it sensibly first.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply; they may have added some extra codes into the registered passwords. Its not a regular crypto so i need to regenerate it from coded string. I may give other account details but they probably added some other chars or strings into it. Bacuause this is too long for a base64 isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar result from using the rijndael algorithm to encrypt plain text, probably thats what they used.

For example: WywsU3TxDO1YYh0d8qnJ6w==